# Can someone provide clarification of "refreshObject:mergeChanges:YES" for me?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Let's say I have a "Person" NSManagedObject class:

```
class Person: NSManagedObject {
    NSManaged var name:String?
    NSManaged var bestFriend:Person?
}
```

How do I ensure that the reference to bestFriend as a "Person" doesn't create a strong reference cycle? I understand that you can use refreshObject:mergeChanges to manage strong references between CoreData objects and create faults so strong references don't persist. What I don't understand is when I use it, or where I call it. Do I use it after I first access the "Person" objects? Do I use it as I'm leaving a view? Before or after a save or delete? If someone could provide some clarification on this I would really appreciate it. Thank you very much!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you not want to persist the `bestFriend` whenever you persist `Person`? Or do you want to memory manage the object graph?

Comment: I want to memory manage the object graph to ensure that strong reference cycles don't occur and cause memory leaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not have any issue with memory leaks (as far as I can understand), the only problem you might have is a bloated object graph which is stored in memory and needs to be "trimmed".

If you want to "trim" the object graph I suggest remove unused objects from the object graph when you are finished with them, otherwise they will just be faulted into the object graph again.

So use `refreshObject:mergeChanges` (with mergeChanges:false) whenever you are finished working with your `Person` and the bestFriend will be turned into a fault.

Comment: ok, thank you for the explanation, I appreciate the help! This was a good response. I used the leaks instrument to check for leaks and did not run into any. Thank you!